# Format to split a column header

Tags: sql

I need to split a column header in a SELECT. For example:

```
select last_name as 'last name', city, state
from address_table
```

I want the columns to look like this:

```
last
name      city       state
```

I cannot get 'last name' to split.

Comment: This is not a function of an RDBMS, but rather the client software Perhaps, though, you could stick a carriage return/line feed character into your column name if it's legal in your RDBMS.

Comment: As @JNevill mentioned, this is a client-side issue. It's also dbms-specific. Please [edit] your question to tell us which client you are using, and [edit] your tags to tell us which dbms you're using. [oracle] [sql-server] [mysql] etc.

Comment: `as 'last name'` is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using? Displaying the column header is also done by the SQL client that you are using to query the database. Which one is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with SQL*Plus using

```
COLUMN ENAME HEADING 'Last|Name'
```